# SignalR how can I get access to claims from connected users?

Tags: c#, .net-core, websocket, signalr

In my application .net core I want to notify the user about some action made by other user.
My SignalR connection is authorized so SignalR should have access to connected user claims, and he has.
[image]

In those claims users have IDs, so I was thinking maybe I can search somehow the user based on that Id, and will send the notification to particualr user, but I've no idea how can I find him in mHubContext, or maybe I should do it in any other way?

Maybe I should override `OnConnected` method and store theirs Id in some static hashset/dictionary?

Comment: One point on thins you can use a userId provider https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections, but it's important to know that a user might have multiple connections if he has multiple tabs open. If possible and you don't have many users you could add a user to a group with user Id as well.

Comment: Why many users have impact on using groups? Groups sounds nice as solution for problem that you meantioned with multiple tabs. If not groups then what?

Comment: Well it really depends on the setup you are running and the backplane type. My recommendation is to try to use AzureSignalRservice and you should not have a problem with groups. As mentioned before connections are a tricky thing in signalR and depends on what you are building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following approach in order to access some properties user, connection, etc.

```
[HubName("demoHub")]
public class DemoHub : Hub
{
    public readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> connections = 
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public override async Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        //await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, Context.QueryString["group"]);
        await base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override async Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        connections.Remove(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        //await Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, Context.QueryString["group"]);
        await base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }

    public override async Task OnReconnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        if (!connections.GetConnections(name).Contains(Context.ConnectionId))
        {
            connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
            //await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, Context.QueryString["group"]);
        }
        await base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

***Update:*** If needed, you can use the following methods or create similar ones using the same logic:

```
public Task JoinToGroup(string groupName)
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}

public Task LeaveFromGroup(string groupName)
{
    return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}

public async Task AddToGroup(string connectionId, string groupName)
{
    await Groups.Add(connectionId, groupName);
    //await Clients.Group(groupName).ReceiveMessage("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
}

public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string connectionId, string groupName)
{
    await Groups.Remove(connectionId, groupName);
    //await Clients.Group(groupName).ReceiveMessage("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has left the group {groupName}.");
}
```

Comment: This isn't a good way to do this: 'In-memory storage does not work if your environment includes more than one web server because each server would have a separate collection of connections.' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Comment: Is there any way to check if group exists? To avoid trying sending message to group that doesn't have any users in.